# Create a dataframe from webscraping string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have an enigmatic issue coming when I try to create a dataFrame.

The following code return a string named period, for which I replaced the double quotes with simple ones, and null by None:

```
import pandas as p
import urllib.request
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

urlsite = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/euroleague/game-center/2023-24/real-madrid-anadolu-efes-istanbul/E2023/170/#play-by-play", context = context)
mybytes = urlsite.read()
texte_orga = mybytes.decode("utf8")
urlsite.close()
bs = "q1\":["
es = "]"
period = texte_orga[texte_orga.find(bs)+4 : texte_orga.find(es,texte_orga.find(bs))+1].replace("\"","\'").replace("null","None")
print(period)
pbp = p.DataFrame(period)
print(pbp)
```

period looks like that (I cut it here because it was too long):

```
[{'playNumber':11,'playType':'BP','playInfo':'Begin Period','teamCode':None,'teamName':None,'playerCode':None,'playerName':None,'playerDorsal':None,'minute':1,'markerTime':None,'homeTeamPoints':None,'awayTeamPoints':None,'nextPlayNumber':None,'deleted':None},{'playNumber':12,'playType':'JB','playInfo':None,'teamCode':'MAD','teamName':'Real Madrid','playerCode':None,'playerName':None,'playerDorsal':None,'minute':1,'markerTime':'09:59','homeTeamPoints':None,'awayTeamPoints':None,'nextPlayNumber':None,'deleted':None},{'playNumber':13,'playType':'TO','playInfo':'Turnover (1)','teamCode':'MAD','teamName':'Real Madrid','playerCode':'P006540','playerName':'MUSA, DZANAN','playerDorsal':'31','minute':1,'markerTime':'09:47','homeTeamPoints':None,'awayTeamPoints':None,'nextPlayNumber':None,'deleted':None}]
```

When I try to create the dataframe from here (last two rows of my code), I have an issue like this:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I tried then by copying the period string manually into s

```
s = [{'playNumber':11,'playType':'BP','playInfo':'Begin Period','teamCode':None,'teamName':None,'playerCode':None,'playerName':None,'playerDorsal':None,'minute':1,'markerTime':None,'homeTeamPoints':None,'awayTeamPoints':None,'nextPlayNumber':None,'deleted':None},{'playNumber':12,'playType':'JB','playInfo':None,'teamCode':'MAD','teamName':'Real Madrid','playerCode':None,'playerName':None,'playerDorsal':None,'minute':1,'markerTime':'09:59','homeTeamPoints':None,'awayTeamPoints':None,'nextPlayNumber':None,'deleted':None},{'playNumber':13,'playType':'TO','playInfo':'Turnover (1)','teamCode':'MAD','teamName':'Real Madrid','playerCode':'P006540','playerName':'MUSA, DZANAN','playerDorsal':'31','minute':1,'markerTime':'09:47','homeTeamPoints':None,'awayTeamPoints':None,'nextPlayNumber':None,'deleted':None}]
pbp = p.DataFrame(s)
print(pbp)
```

And...it works! Do you know why?

Comment: `period` is a string, not a list. You can't create DataFrame with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ast
pbp = p.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(period))
```

This is because `period` is not a dictionary but actually a string